# Cached data with PDF report in reportlab

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm using reportlab with django for one of my project to generate dynamic PDF report. I'm using  tag in Paragraph.

I'm getting the output correctly, but if change the image from django admin page then image in report is not changing.

Is it Caching problem?

If so how can i resolve it?